# Left join to empty data using linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, ef-core-3.1

I have the following query in MySQL.

```sql
SELECT Pages.*, IFNULL(PagePermission.CanRead, 0) CanRead, IFNULL(PagePermission.CanWrite, 0) CanWrite, IFNULL(PagePermission.CanDelete, 0) CanDelete
FROM (SELECT * FORM Pages WHERE IsVisible = 1) Pages
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT PermissionPages.PageId, MAX(PermissionPages.CanRead) CanRead, MAX(PermissionPages.CanWrite) CanWrite, MAX(PermissionPages.CanDelete) CanDelete 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM Permissions WHERE IsActive = 1) Permissions
  INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM PermissionUsers WHERE UserId = @userId) PermissionUsers ON Permissions.PermissionId = PermissionUsers.PermissionId
  INNER JOIN PermissionPages ON Permissions.PermissionId = PermissionPages.PermissionId
  GROUP BY PermissionPages.PageId
) PagePermission ON Pages.PageId = PagePermission.PageId
```

Here, the value of `@userId` is coming from the application; and for newly created user (i.e.- the user whose page permissions are not defined yet), the result of `PagePermission` will be empty.

Now, I am trying to write this query in LINQ and execute the new query considering the mentioned condition.

For this purpose, initially I wrote the following query.

```cs
var result = (from pages in Pages.Where(x => x.IsVisible)
              join pagePermission in (from permissions in Permissions.Where(x => x.IsActive)
                                      join permissionUsers in PermissionUsers.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                                      on permissions.PermissionId equals permissionUsers.PermissionId
                                      join permissionPages in PermissionPages
                                      on permissions.PermissionId equals permissionPages.PermissionId
                                      group permissionPages by permissionPages.PageId into groupedPermissionPages
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          PageId = groupedPermissionPages.Key,
                                          CanRead = groupedPermissionPages.Select(p => p.CanRead).Max(),
                                          CanWrite = groupedPermissionPages.Select(p => p.CanWrite).Max(),
                                          CanDelete = groupedPermissionPages.Select(p => p.CanDelete).Max()
                                      })
              on pages.PageId equals pagePermission.PageId into pagePermissionJoined
              from pagePermission in pagePermissionJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new PagePermissionResult
              {
                  PageId = pages.PageId,
                  PageName = pages.PageName,
                  .....
                  .....
                  CanRead = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanRead),
                  CanWrite = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanWrite),
                  CanDelete = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanDelete)
              }).ToList();
```

When I tried executing this query for a new user, I got the following exception.

```
The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (t.PageId), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: PermissionPages
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)
)
    .Select(p => p.CanRead)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

After this, I modified the query to this:

```cs
var result = (from pages in Pages.Where(x => x.IsVisible)
              join pagePermission in (from permissions in Permissions.Where(x => x.IsActive)
                                      join permissionUsers in PermissionUsers.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                                      on permissions.PermissionId equals permissionUsers.PermissionId
                                      join permissionPages in PermissionPages
                                      on permissions.PermissionId equals permissionPages.PermissionId
                                      select permissionPages).ToList()
                                                             .GroupBy(x => new { PageId = x.PageId })
                                                             .Select(x => new 
                                                             {
                                                                 PageId = x.Key.PageId,
                                                                 CanRead = x.Select(p => p.CanRead).Max(),
                                                                 CanWrite = x.Select(p => p.CanWrite).Max(),
                                                                 CanDelete = x.Select(p => p.CanDelete).Max()
                                                             })
              on pages.PageId equals pagePermission.PageId into pagePermissionJoined
              from pagePermission in pagePermissionJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new PagePermissionResult
              {
                  PageId = pages.PageId,
                  PageName = pages.PageName,
                  .....
                  .....
                  CanRead = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanRead),
                  CanWrite = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanWrite),
                  CanDelete = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanDelete)
              }).ToList();
```

Executing this query for new user resulted in the following exception:

```
Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<Pages>
    .Where(x => x.IsVisible)
    .LeftJoin(
        outer: __p_1
            .AsQueryable(), 
        inner: pages => pages.PageId, 
        outerKeySelector: pagePermission => pagePermission.PageId, 
        innerKeySelector: (pages, pagePermission) => new PagePermissionResult{ 
            PageId = pages.PageId, 
            PageName = pages.PageName, 
            ..... 
            ..... 
            CanRead = pagePermission == null ? False : pagePermission.CanRead, 
            CanWrite = pagePermission == null ? False : pagePermission.CanWrite, 
            CanDelete = pagePermission == null ? False : pagePermission.CanDelete 
        }
    )' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
```

Then, I modified the query to this:

```cs
var result = (from pages in Pages.Where(x => x.IsVisible)
              join pagePermission in (from permissions in Permissions.Where(x => x.IsActive)
                                      join permissionUsers in PermissionUsers.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                                      on permissions.PermissionId equals permissionUsers.PermissionId
                                      join permissionPages in PermissionPages
                                      on permissions.PermissionId equals permissionPages.PermissionId
                                      select permissionPages).ToList()
                                                             .GroupBy(x => new { PageId = x.PageId })
                                                             .Select(x => new 
                                                             {
                                                                 PageId = x.Key.PageId,
                                                                 CanRead = x.Select(p => p.CanRead).Max(),
                                                                 CanWrite = x.Select(p => p.CanWrite).Max(),
                                                                 CanDelete = x.Select(p => p.CanDelete).Max()
                                                             })
              on pages.PageId equals pagePermission.PageId into pagePermissionJoined
              from pagePermission in pagePermissionJoined.DefaultIfEmpty(new { PageId = pages.PageId, CanRead = false, CanWrite = false, CanDelete = false })
              select new PagePermissionResult
              {
                  PageId = pages.PageId,
                  PageName = pages.PageName,
                  .....
                  .....
                  CanRead = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanRead),
                  CanWrite = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanWrite),
                  CanDelete = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanDelete)
              }).ToList();
```

This query generates the following exception for new user:

```
Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType23`5[System.Int32,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean]]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType23`5[System.Int32,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean]]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType23`5[System.Int32,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean]] Where[<>f__AnonymousType23`5](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType23`5[System.Int32,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType23`5[System.Int32,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean],System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg0')
```

To identify the anonymous type generating the exception, I modified the query to this:

```cs
var result = (from pages in Pages.Where(x => x.IsVisible)
              join pagePermission in (from permissions in Permissions.Where(x => x.IsActive)
                                      join permissionUsers in PermissionUsers.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                                      on permissions.PermissionId equals permissionUsers.PermissionId
                                      join permissionPages in PermissionPages
                                      on permissions.PermissionId equals permissionPages.PermissionId
                                      select permissionPages).ToList()
                                                             .GroupBy(x => new { PageId = x.PageId })
                                                             .Select(x => new PermissionPages
                                                             {
                                                                 PageId = x.Key.PageId,
                                                                 CanRead = x.Select(p => p.CanRead).Max(),
                                                                 CanWrite = x.Select(p => p.CanWrite).Max(),
                                                                 CanDelete = x.Select(p => p.CanDelete).Max()
                                                             })
              on pages.PageId equals pagePermission.PageId into pagePermissionJoined
              from pagePermission in pagePermissionJoined.DefaultIfEmpty(new PermissionPages { PageId = pages.PageId, CanRead = false, CanWrite = false, CanDelete = false })
              select new PagePermissionResult
              {
                  PageId = pages.PageId,
                  PageName = pages.PageName,
                  .....
                  .....
                  CanRead = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanRead),
                  CanWrite = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanWrite),
                  CanDelete = (pagePermission == null ? false : pagePermission.CanDelete)
              }).ToList();
```

This modification changes the generated exception to this:

```
Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PermissionPages]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[PermissionPages]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[PermissionPages] Where[PermissionPages](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[PermissionPages], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[PermissionPages,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg0')
```

At this point, I am not sure what else can I do to run the query for users whose permissions are not defined.

I did not include scenarios where users with defined permissions are used to generate the result - as the data for that kind of user could simply be fetched using inner join.

Also, while I could get the data of `pagePermission` in a separate query, and then use that result to generate the final `PagePermissionResult` data; I am not doing this to avoid repeated DB access.

Thank you in advance for taking your time to read the question and suggesting me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original LINQ query is fine. You simply are hitting EF Core 3.1 query translation bug. EF Core 3.1 is quite outdated, with many bugs (especially in `GroupBy` translation) fixed in the recent versions.

Here the problem seems to be (as indicated by the original error) `Select` expressions like

```cs
x.Select(p => p.CanRead).Max()
```

inside `GroupBy` result selector.

The workaround is to simply use the "shortcut" versions of the LINQ aggregate methods, e.g. in your original query

```cs
CanRead = x.Max(p => p.CanRead),
CanWrite = x.Max(p => p.CanWrite),
CanDelete = x.Max(p => p.CanDelete)
```

Comment: This is an interesting explanation. While I found out about some of the EF Core 3.1 issues, I did not consider them when trying to fix this issue. The suggested approach actually worked. Thank you.

Comment: Just asking this question due to curiosity - when I was trying to solve the issue, I tried following your suggestion in my linq queries - your suggestion worked only in my 1st linq query. Is there any reason behind such behavior? Is this behavior related to some other ef core bug - or is there something else?

Comment: @Muntasir Not sure I follow the question, but let me try. Once I verified that your first LINQ query is correct, this for me was clear indication that the problem is in EF Core. I did not try to evaluate your next attempts, because all variations which include intermediate `ToList()`, `AsEnumerable()` and similar change the execution plan of the LINQ query (and queries based on it) - it's no more evaluated fully server side, so one have to account other client side evaluation factors/limitation like the need of `Inlcude`s, are related subqueries already evaluated/available at the time the ...

Comment: master query is materialized in memory, etc. From my experience, going in that direction is a last resort, only when all attempts to write a fully server side translatable query fail. The process is some kind of similar we wrote SQLs back in the days (the only difference is that it was for solving perf issues) - you write the query using equivalent syntax (there are always several ways to do one and the same goal) and see if that helps (the EF Core query translator in this case) to do its job. Translating expression trees is quite complicated thing, so it's normal to have bugs/missing cases.

Comment: Oh, ok ... I guess? Thank you for taking the time to reply to the follow-up question.